# Image projection in Matlab with Hough transform

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I am using Matlab to input a 4x4 grid of coloured squares, and output a list of colours. My program works fine for squares, but I am having trouble adapting it to rotated images:

[image: Rotated 1]

[image: Rotated 2]

and projected images:

[image: Projected]

---

I have been advised to use **Hough transforms**, and I am able to use this to access the lines in the image with the following code:

```
[H, theta, rho] = hough(image,'RhoResolution',0.1,'Theta',-90:0.5:89.5);    
peaks = houghpeaks(H,4);    
lines = houghlines(dilated, theta, rho, peaks, 'MinLength', 40)

figure, imshow(dilated), hold on;

max_len = 0;

for k = 1:length(lines)

   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];

   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');    
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   angle = atand(((xy(1,1)-xy(2,1))/(xy(1,2)-xy(2,2))));  

end
```

So now I would like to use these lines, and straighten my image accordingly, so that image edges are parallel with these lines. However, I don't know how to go about this. I would appreciate advice on how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `dilated` come from? How to you calculate the black-white image and the edges from it? Canny? Sobel? Prewitt?

Maybe you are using a derivative filter which is dependend on the angle of the edges and therefore you maybe won't get a good edge-image off it which would make the Houghtransformation fail as it can only work on good images containing well-defined edges with  possibly closed edges (or at least small gaps).

So as a hint: just output your black-white image via `imshow(dilated)` and look at it to see, how well defined the edges are, especially in comparison to edges of an image without rotation.